# Is it possible to assign every item from one list to every item from another list respectively? Or, if not, what is the better way to do it?

Tags: python, list, loops, variable-assignment

Let's say I have some amount of pictures that I want to use in my python code. To use them, I need to open them all with `open()` and assign them to variables. But what if there's a lot of pictures? Assigning every one of them would take a lot of time.

So, I thought maybe I could automate the process by using lists and tried something like this:

```
list1 = []
for i in range(1, 100):
    list1.append('pic'+str(i))

list2 = []
for i in range(1, 100):
    list2.append( '= open("C:\\example\\pic"' + str(i) + '".jpg", "rb"')

for i, u in list1, list2:
    i = u
```

But I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\example.py", line 9, in <module>
    for i, u in list1, list2:
        ^^^^
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I kind of understand why it doesn't work but at the same time I can't think of a better way to do this.

Comment: `for i, u in zip(list1, list):`. But why are you immediately assigning to `i`? Are you expecting that to update `list1`?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables. If you want to refer to your images as `pic1` etc (rather than just use list indices) you could create a dictionary with `pic1`, `pic2` etc as the keys, and the image objects as the values.

Comment: Or do expect that to update the variable `pic1, pic2, ...`?

Comment: @Barmar I *think* by `i = u` OP is trying to execute the statement that would be generated by concatenating `i + u`.